# Trying to set inner HTML on span element on submit of form - doesn't display

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Bit of a newbie question here. Trying to implement a simple tip calculator and display the results below the form that the user submits with the bill amount and the tip percentage. The function that fires on submit successfully does the calculation - the correct amounts are alerted (the alerts are just in for checking), however the span elements either don't get the inner HTML or the page immediately reloads so that they don't persist. How do I get the amounts to display and remain?

```
<form id="tipCalculator">
      <label for="billAmount">Enter Bill Amount:</label>
      <input type="number" name="billAmount" id="billAmount">
      <label for="tipPercent">Enter Tip Percentage:</label>
      <input type="number" name="tipPercent" id="tipPercent">
      <input type="submit" onclick= "calcTip()" name="submitButton" value="Calculate Tip">
    </form>
    <div id=displayResultArea>
      <p>Tip Amount:<span id=displayTipAmount></span></p>
      <p>Total Bill:<span id=displayTotalAmount></span></p>
    </div>
  </main>

<script type="text/javascript">
function calcTip() {
    let billAmnt = document.getElementById('billAmount').value;
    let tipPrcnt = document.getElementById('tipPercent').value;
    let billAmntNum = parseFloat(billAmnt);
    let tipPrcntNum = parseFloat(tipPrcnt);
    let tipAmnt = billAmntNum * (tipPrcntNum / 100);
    let billTotal = billAmntNum + tipAmnt;
    alert(tipAmnt);
    alert(billTotal);
    document.getElementById('displayTipAmount').innerHTML = tipAmnt;
    document.getElementById('displayTotalAmount').innerHTML = billTotal;
  }
```

Comment: You know you're submitting the form to your server?

Comment: just change to `<input type="button" onclick="calcTip()" name="submitButton" value="Calculate Tip">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use need to prevent default form behaviour, use event.preventDefault();

```js
function calcTip(event) {
    let billAmnt = document.getElementById('billAmount').value;
    let tipPrcnt = document.getElementById('tipPercent').value;
    let billAmntNum = parseFloat(billAmnt);
    let tipPrcntNum = parseFloat(tipPrcnt);
    let tipAmnt = billAmntNum * (tipPrcntNum / 100);
    let billTotal = billAmntNum + tipAmnt;
    //alert(tipAmnt);
    //alert(billTotal);
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById('displayTipAmount').innerHTML = tipAmnt;
    document.getElementById('displayTotalAmount').innerHTML = billTotal;
  }
```

```html
<input type="submit" onclick= "calcTip(event)" name="submitButton" value="Calculate Tip">
```

Comment: That got it. Thanks everyone, I'll upvote the button answer too as that had half the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are seeing the page reload is because you are submiting the form which is posting a request to the backend.

You can prevent the request being posted by adding prevent default like so:

```
function calcTip() {
    event.preventDefault()
    let billAmnt = document.getElementById('billAmount').value;
    let tipPrcnt = document.getElementById('tipPercent').value;
    let billAmntNum = parseFloat(billAmnt);
    let tipPrcntNum = parseFloat(tipPrcnt);
    let tipAmnt = billAmntNum * (tipPrcntNum / 100);
    let billTotal = billAmntNum + tipAmnt;
    alert(tipAmnt);
    alert(billTotal);
    document.getElementById('displayTipAmount').innerHTML = tipAmnt;
    document.getElementById('displayTotalAmount').innerHTML = billTotal;
  }
```

If you want to submit the form elsewhere i would reccomend changing the submit input to the following as it may be confusing to have two submit buttons

```
 <button onclick="calcTip()" name="submitButton" >Calculate Tip</button>
```

Comment: This won't work, the default action of a button element wrapped in a form is to submit the form.

Comment: your are right @Teemu he need to change to button type.

Comment: I had thought that I had to use submit but remove action so it submitted to the same page. So I changed to your suggestion and the spans get the inner html now, but the page still reloads and everything resets. Can I stop this happening? Should I not be using a form at all?

Comment: If you are not going to be sending any of this data to an api then i would not use a form @AlistairJenkins

Answer (score 0):

Try to change to below line `input` `type` from `submit` to `button`

`<input type="button" onclick="calcTip()" name="submitButton" value="Calculate Tip">`